# Play: How and where to create a private file programmatically

Tags: scala, playframework

I read some documentation and it looks like private custom files should be placed in the `conf` directory.

The code to read `conf/foo/foo.txt` would be

```
InputStream in = MyClass.class. getResourceAsStream("/foo/bar.txt")
```

... but I need to create a file in a sub-directory of `conf` programmatically... and I'm wondering whether this is the correct way to go:

```
import play.api.Play.current
val dir = File(application.path.getPath + "/conf/foo/")
if (!dir.exits) dir.mkDir
val file = new File(...)
...
```

Does Play provide any helper for this?

Comment: You probably shouldn't create files in `conf/` at runtime.

Comment: I agree...Do not store your files in conf directory. Imagine that you have a server and you need to change version. Entire unversioned files will be deleted from your project and I don't think you want to keep each file in git/svn repository. 
Better approach is to make path to external plate on your disc.

Comment: @MichałWolnicki write an answer.